# Qlikview is ETL testing tool or development tool?

Tags: etl, qlikview

As I am a manual tester I wanted to know Qlikview is **ETL testing tool** or **development tool**?

And is there any advantage of this tool in Automation of ETL testing?

Answer (score 2):

Because QlikView offers both scripting and front end tools it could be, and is, used for both.

The scripting engine can do any ETL you might require and via the front end visualisation engine you could build tests for any cases you want to test for. The nature of QliView would also allows you easy access, and filtering of any individual data lines causing problems.

I've used it this way for large data migration and management projects.

There are no doubt more specialised tools, i.e. there are no inbuilt tools for common scenario testing, you have to build it all yourself and export via excel or csv, but it can be done.